# ORA-7445 kills PMON instance

Tags: restore, oracle-12c, errors, rman

I restored an Oracle 12.1.0.2 database using RMAN full backup from a RAC+ASM enviroment to single instance enviroment with less memory and cpu (for test purposes) using this document Doc ID 1338193.1.
After restore, I open the database and all pdbs (5 pdbs) are READ & WRITE. After 5-10 min, alert log show this errors and the database is shuting down.

```
Exception [type: SIGSERV, SI_KERNEL(general_protection)] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x2A22942, kgscDump()+150] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/test/test/trace/test_smon_5233.trc (incident=1424259) (PDBNAME=TEST)
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [joxdmp_()+80] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x3EE3EB0][SI_KERNEL(general_protection)][]
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [rpisplu_internal()+290] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x2A22942] [SI_KERNEL(general_protection)][]
```

After this errors comes the hard one.

```
Process 0x0x1049570b70 appears to be hung while dumping 
Attempting to kill process 0x1049570b70 with OS pid = 5233 
OSD kill succeeded for process 0x1049570b70 
Instance Critical Process died unexpectedly PMON: terminating the instance due to error 474 
Instance terminated by PMON
```

As you can see the error comes from (PDBNAME=TEST). If I start the database and I stop the TEST pdb, I have no error and the database is up and running except this pdb. Do you have any idea how can I resolve this errors? I validated all database from corruption using rman validation (and logically).

Comment: For an internal error like that you should contact Oracle Support.

Comment: This test was just for learning purposes. I don't want to open a SR for that, I just want to understand what is wrong in this DB.

Comment: With that kind of error, which is potentially very serious, only Oracle Support can tell you what the real problem is.

Comment: And has that database been patched up to date?

Comment: After restore I patched the database like source (12.1.0.2.DBBP:200714)